# The dual of a linear program for weighted distance

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

My orignal problem is to simply find the minimum of $\sum_i^nq_i|x_i-u|$, where $q_i > 0$
I firstly convert to a standard linear program format as:

> $min_u\sum_i^nq_i*t_i$
>
> $t_i  >= u - x_i $
> $t_i >= x_i - u$
> $u,x_i >= 0 \; \forall i = 1,2,...,n$

I was trying to find the dual of this, and I got:

> $max\sum_i^n((\lambda_{1i} - \lambda_{2i})(u-x_i) $ 
> $\lambda_{1i} + \lambda_{2i} <= q_i$ 
> $\lambda_{1i},\lambda_{2i} >= 0$ 
> $\forall i = 1,2,3,...,n$

It looks really strange to me, the $u$ is also unknown parameter (as $\lambda$)but how to optimize it in this dual program? 
I also think: when $u > x_i$ just choose $\lambda_{1i} = q_i, \lambda_{2i} = 0$, and when $u < x_i$, choose $\lambda_{1i} = 0, \lambda_{2i} = q_i$,could gurrante a maximum value. But this is actually the original format $\sum_i^nq_i|x_i-u|$. This makes me confused.

Is there something wrong when I convert the primal to dual problem?

Comment: It would be good that you detail the problem. Find the minimum for which variable, $u$? What are the hypothesis on $q_i, x_i$? For example if $i = 1$ and $q_1 <0$, there will be no minimum.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, for $u$. for u, $q_i, x_i$ they all positive numbers. Thank you for pointing out.